# Sort Array by highest value google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following spreadsheet:

```
| Name | Rating |
| John | 2000   |
| Jane | 50     |
| Bill | 3000   |
| Sam  | 500    |
```

I get the data for the spreadsheet in the following way:

```
mySheet.getDataRange().getValues();
```

My goal is to print the array from highest rating to lowest rating. How can I do that?

EDIT: I probably should mention I am aware of the sort function: However, the issue there is it sorts as a string, not a number. Which means that 60 will show above 2000 because it starts with a 6.

Comment: Use Utilities to format as a number, sort them and then reformat as string?

Comment: What's keeping you from using the spreadsheet's SORT() function? it certainly can sort by numeric value.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a comparator function to the sort() method.

```
function sortDescending() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
  var values = range.getValues();

  values.sort(function(a, b){

  return b[1] - a[1]; //sorts by the 2nd element in a row


  });

  Logger.log(values);
  }
```

Note that I skipped the header row and didn't include it in the list of values to sort. Hope this helps.